# ¿Cómo puedo asociar un hidden con un checkbox

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy intentando hacer que cuando el cliente oprima el checkbox, este tome el valor de el hidden que esta abajo, algo así como si cada checkbox tuviera un hidden que le corresponde, y lo guarde en la base de datos

Este es mi codigo

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SoftAOX | Insert Checkbox values in Database using Ajax, Jquery & 
PHP</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Insert Checkbox values in Database using Ajax, Jquery in PHP</h3>

<input type="checkbox" id="Apple" class="get_value" value="Apple">
<label>Apple</label><br/>
<input type="hidden" id="Apple" class="get_other_value" value="Two">
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="IBM"><label>IBM</label><br/>
<input type="hidden" class="get_other_value" value="Two">
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="Google">
<label>Google</label><br/>
<input type="hidden" class="get_other_value" value="Three">
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="Microsoft">
<label>Microsoft</label><br/>
<input type="hidden" class="get_other_value" value="Four">
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="Amazon">
<label>Amazon</label><br/>
<input type="hidden" class="get_other_value" value="Five">
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
<br/>
<h4 id="result"></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
var insert = [];
$('.get_value').each(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
insert.push($('input[type=hidden]:checked', this).val());
}
});
insert = insert.toString();
$.ajax({
url: "insert1.php",
method: "POST",
data:{insert:insert},
success:function(data){
$('#result').html(data);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","datos1");
$query= "INSERT INTO BOOKS(name) VALUES('".$_POST["insert"]."') ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo "Data Inserted Succesfully";
}
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta ni tu código, si lo organizas con tabulaciones se leería mucho mejor

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Sí, está un poco raro el código

Comment: Lo que quiero es que cuando oprima un checkbox, este tome el value de el hidden de abajo de ese checkbox. Intente esto pero no funcionó    insert.push($('input[type=hidden]:checked', this).val());

Comment: Y porque en vez de usar un hidden no usas el mismo checkbox pero le agregas un atributo por ejemplo **<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="IBM" data-hidden="Two" />**

Comment: Pero luego como hago para que cuando el usuario haga click en el checkbox este cambie el valor de el checkbox por el de el data-hidden

Comment: Y pues hice esto-> insert.push($(this).attr("value","data-hidden")); pero en la base de datos me guardo fue [Object, object]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, agregale un id o un nombre al input[type=hidden]

```
 var valor = $("input[name='input_hidden']").val();
```

Comment: Pues ya lo logre hacer, lo que hice fue ponerle un id a cada checkbox, y luego cuando el usuario hiciera click, puse el metodo attr para que me mostrara el id y no el value

Comment: Buena, bro, me alegro!

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor simplemente ponerle un id a el input y luego simplemente con attr haces que te muestre el valor de su id

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
var insert = [];
$('.get_value').each(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
insert.push($(this).attr("id"));
}
});
insert = insert.toString();
$.ajax({
url: "insert1.php",
method: "POST",
data:{insert:insert},
success:function(data){
$('#result').html(data);
}
});
});
});
```